# Can I execute code on Google Drive server infra?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

Does Google Drive API provide a way to execute my code on the Google Drive server infra?

Let's say I want to write Google Dirve based `grep` to let customer search through thier files.
I want to be able to write something like this: (very simplified to make it short)

```
/* define the function for grep */
var grep = function(params, callback) {
  // 1) find all text files using `gapi.client.drive.files.list`
  // 2) open each file with `gapi.client.drive.files.get`
  // 3) scan for the serach string occurance
  callback(search_result);
}

/* register the code on the server with imaginary API */
gapi.client.drive.server.register('myapp.grep', grep);

/* execute from Browser */
gapi.client.drive.server.myapp.grep({searchString: 'Abrakadabra', mimeType: 'application/javascript'},
  function(resutls) {
    console.log(results)
  }
);
```

There are tons of application types can take advantage of this approach. *Simple DB manager* is another example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is [Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/) and [Google App Engine](https://developers.google.com/appengine/) which is quiet close to what you want. I don't think Google Drive has that feature.