# Installing Node.js on Google Drive (or using Google Drive to run your web app)

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-drive-api

I would like to know if it is at all possible, or has been attempted to install Node.js on Google Drive or run a multi-player web app from Google Drive?

Google Drive can be used as a web server to host your website.

Sadly, I am simply an ambitious and motivated coding noob, however, my research has yielded no answers to this question. Perhaps I am not looking at things the right way, is this something that would be done with the Google Drive API?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

[Google does not allow you to run any own content in the Google drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17246615/can-i-execute-code-on-google-drive-server-infra), it is a simple cloud storage. HTML pages are static and not processed on the server, that's why they work. It does on the Google App Engine, but the Google App Engine does not support node.js.

You can find a list of supported hosting providers in the [node wiki](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Node-Hosting).

Comment: https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client/

Would this make it possible?

Comment: @user3450602 It is an API client for node JS. It does not allow you to run a server.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible:

> With Drive, you can make web resources — like HTML, CSS, and
>   Javascript files — viewable as a website. [...] Google Drive does not
>   support web resources that make use of server-side scripting languages
>   like PHP.

[Source](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2881970?hl=en)